# What is Wrong between Codeblocks 20.3 and minGW_x64_Win_Build?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am getting the following error on the execution. Compiler I am using is minGW_x64_Win_Build. The Locations, Directories and everything is in the Correct State.
Don't Know but is the Internal bug.

> ```
> ||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
> F:\CodeBlocks Training\Completed Programs\Calculator 0.cpp|38|fatal error: x64: No such file or directory|
> || === Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
> ```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void MainMenu();
void Decision(double, double);

int main()
{
    MainMenu();
    double userInput1;
    double userInput2;
    cout << " Enter Your Choice: " << '\n';
    cin >> userInput1;
    cout << " Enter Your Second Choice: " << '\n';
    cin >> userInput2;
    Decision(userInput2, userInput2);
    return 0;
}
void MainMenu()
{
    cout << " Enter Your choice" << '\n';
    cout << " -----------------" << '\n';
    cout << " 1 for Addition" << '\n';
    cout << " 2 for Subtraction" << '\n';
    cout << " 3 for Multiplication" << '\n';
    cout << " 4 for Division" << '\n';
    cout << " -----------------" <<'\n';
}
void Decision(double userInput1, double userInput2)
{
    int R_usr;
    switch (R_usr)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << " The Result for the entered values: " << userInput1 << " and " << userInput2 << " is equal to: (" << userInput1 + userInput2 << ")" <<'\n';
        break;
    }
}
```

SNAP SHOT

[image]

COMPILER

[image]

Comment: On execution of the switch? No, the error states that the build failed, because a file was not found.

Comment: You meant to write `int userInput2;` rather than `double userInput2;` same for the  `Decision()` function. VTC as typo.

Comment: @churill File is their I double checked and even a .cpp format.

Comment: @Tahir The compiler error shown, has nothing to do with your switch statement. It pretty clearly just says that the file specified cannot be found.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The use can enter a double value with your solution?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why it does not find the file? While the file is created by Codeblocks itself a calculator0.cpp

Comment: @Tahir Yes, but the switch won't accept it.

Comment: @Tahir Well, check your project settings, where the compiler looks up the source files.

Comment: @Tahir BTW, why are you asking a question about your switch statement, when it's clear that this can't be the source of the problem, and you read and understood the compiler error message?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Without switch statement it has not any problem and the search directories is also defaults and working well

Comment: @Tahir Adding a `switch` statement certainly cannot move the source file elsewhere, that the compiler won't find it anymore. That's not your problem, trust me.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Solved, Downgraded from v20.3

Comment: @Tahir Whatever, doesn't have to do anything with the switch statement as I mentioned. _shrug_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes I have changed the Title.

Comment: @Tahir If you would now could manage to provide a [mcve] without all the completely irrelevant source code (e.g. let's say a _Hello World_ compilation unit), you might convince me to vote for reopening the question as being useful for future readers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No Thanks Man, I don't need to reopen this topic because My Problem is solved.

Comment: @Tahir _"My Problem is solved"_ Note that the whole purpose of Stack Overflow isn't to solve your personal problems, but to provide a FAQ like repository to be helpful in future research. With that attitude, You're probably in the wrong place here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If anyone will have this problem in the future they will post and open the new thread because it's for the research purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is Solved.

> Downgraded from 20.3 to Codeblocks 17.12

Working Fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

void optionManue();
void userDecision_(int);

double resultAddition(double,double);
double resultSubtraction(double,double);
double resultMultiplication(double,double);
double resultDivision(double,double);
bool isvalid_(string);

int main()
{
    int userChoice_;
    char restart_;
    do{
    system("cls");
    optionManue();
    cout<< " Enter the Choice: ";
    while (!(cin>>userChoice_))
    {
        system("cls");
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>:: max(), '\n');
        system("cls");
        cout<< " Wrong choice detected! Illegal stance stopped! Try again." << '\n';
        cout<< " *********************************************************" << '\n';
        optionManue();
        cout<< " Enter the Choice: ";
    }
    userDecision_(userChoice_);
    do{
        cin.clear();
        cout << " Do you want to Restart the App? [Y/n] " ;
        cin >> restart_;
        system("cls");
        optionManue();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        }while (restart_!='Y'&&restart_!='y'&&restart_!='N'&&restart_!='n');
    }while (restart_ == 'Y' || restart_ == 'y');
    return 0;
}
void optionManue()
{
    cout << " -----------------------------------------------------------" << '\n';
    cout << " Select the option by Following Numbers that you want to use" << '\n';
    cout << " -----------------------------------------------------------" << '\n';
    cout << " 1 for + Addition " << '\n';
    cout << " 2 for - Subtraction " << '\n';
    cout << " 3 for * Multiplication " << '\n';
    cout << " 4 for / Division " << '\n';
    cout << " --------------------------------------------------" << '\n';
}
void userDecision_(int userChoice_)
{
    double
    userValueAdd_1, userValueAdd_2,
    userValueSub_1, userValueSub_2,
    userValueMul_1, userValueMul_2,
    userValueDiv_1, userValueDiv_2;
    switch(userChoice_)
    {
    case 1:do{cout<< " Enter the values for Addition"<<'\n'; cout << " First Value: ";cin>>userValueAdd_1;cout<< " Second Value: ";cin>> userValueAdd_2;}while(!isvalid_("Ops! Entered invalid value, Try again."));
    resultAddition(userValueAdd_1, userValueAdd_2);
    break;
    case 2:do{cout<< " Enter the values for Subtraction"<<'\n'; cout << " First Value: ";cin>>userValueSub_1;cout<< " Second Value: ";cin>> userValueSub_2;}while(!isvalid_("Ops! Entered invalid value, Try again."));
    resultSubtraction(userValueSub_1, userValueSub_2);
    break;
    case 3:do{cout<< " Enter the values for Multiplication"<<'\n'; cout << " First Value: ";cin>>userValueMul_1;cout<< " Second Value: ";cin>> userValueMul_2;}while(!isvalid_("Ops! Entered invalid value, Try again."));
    resultMultiplication(userValueMul_1, userValueMul_2);
    break;
    case 4:do{cout<< " Enter the values for Division"<<'\n'; cout << " First Value: ";cin>>userValueDiv_1;cout<< " Second Value: ";cin>> userValueDiv_2;}while(!isvalid_("Ops! Entered invalid value, Try again."));
    resultDivision(userValueDiv_1, userValueDiv_2);
    break;
    default:
        cout<<" Not allowed input! Try again with legal or allowed characters or Escape." << '\n';
    }
}
double resultAddition(double userValueAdd_1,double userValueAdd_2)
{
    double ResultAd = userValueAdd_1 + userValueAdd_2;
    cout<< " The addition of " << userValueAdd_1 << " and " << userValueAdd_2 << " is = " << ResultAd << '\n';
}
double resultSubtraction(double userValueSub_1,double userValueSub_2)
{
    double Resultsub = userValueSub_1 - userValueSub_2;
    cout<< " The addition of " << userValueSub_1 << " and " << userValueSub_2 << " is = " << Resultsub << '\n';
}
double resultMultiplication(double userValueMul_1,double userValueMul_2)
{
    double Resultmul = userValueMul_1 * userValueMul_2;
    cout<< " The addition of " << userValueMul_1 << " and " << userValueMul_2 << " is = " << Resultmul << '\n';
}
double resultDivision(double userValueDiv_1,double userValueDiv_2)
{
    double Resultdiv = userValueDiv_1 / userValueDiv_2;
    cout<< " The addition of " << userValueDiv_1 << " and " << userValueDiv_2 << " is = " << Resultdiv << '\n';
}

bool isvalid_(string err_msg)
{
    if(cin.rdstate())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>:: max(), '\n');
        system("cls");
        optionManue();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your switch statement examines an uninitialised variable.

Comment: How would you expect that fixing this could solve the problem described by OP? The problem you describe would only occur at runtime, which OP obviously cannot even get to... (Downvote however is not by me.) As a comment on the question, this would make sense. So why did you not use your commenting privilege?

Comment: Because I did not have one at the time.  Also, the initial summary was "what is wrong with my switch", so this is the exact answer.

Comment: Sorry that I was not aware of the history of your privileges. An impressive demonstration how to earn quite a lot of reputation in a few days by the way. My respect.

Comment: The history of the question however supports my other question. Already in version one of the question OP clearly discusses a copmile time problem, which cannot be caused by an uninitialised variable. You'd have to only read the title and the code, i.e. ignore all other provided information, to argue that OP wants a review of the switch statement.